# How to manage a userfriendly .env in git?

Tags: git, github, environment-variables

I am trying to push a .env file into my repo on github which should only contain the variable names without any data, so it is easier for others to use the .env for configuration.
Afterwards I add `.env` to my gitignore file but it keeps tracking the .env and pushes it onto my repo whenever I commit a push. So here is my question how do you manage to have a .env file without pushing your personal data and overwrite it ?

Comment: The way it's usually done is having a `.env.default` (or similar) in git which is copied to `.env` on initial install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways one can achieve this.

I believe the most standard one is to have an `.example` file in your repo, which will then be changed for each user of the project. So you'll just have an `XYZ.env.example` and you'll locally "implement" `env.example` (by this I mean that you'll take `.env.example` and make a valid `.env` config file). With this approach, you'll have to track `XYZ.env.example` and **ignore** `XYZ.env`.

---

Another way is to use `git update-index --[no]-skip-worktree`.

From the documentation:

> Skip-worktree bit can be defined in one (long) sentence: When reading an entry, if it is marked as skip-worktree, then Git pretends its working directory version is up to date and read the index version instead.
>
> To elaborate, "reading" means checking for file existence, reading file attributes or file content. The working directory version may be present or absent. If present, its content may match against the index version or
> not. Writing is not affected by this bit, content safety is still first priority. Note that Git can update working directory file, that is marked skip-worktree, if it is safe to do so (i.e. working directory version
> matches index version)

This means that you can keep your **initial** `XYZ.env` file the way one should see it without production/test/debug values and then you can *freely* change it without git bugging you for these changes.

You **can** update the file if you need to and you **can** push new changes. Simply unmark the file with `git update-index --no-skip-worktree`.

Keep in mind that if remote introduces changes to `.env`, then you`ll conflict locally (which is a good thing).

One last thing - this command works only locally. **Every** contributor (if he/she wishes to) must do this on their local clone.